# Interpolation between two points, am I missing something?

Tags: c, interpolation, physics

I am trying to do a linear interpolation between two know positions. Previous position and current position.

```
float x,y, p_x, p_y;
```

i call this update function at fixed intervals.

```
update(float _x, float _y) {
    p_x = x;
    p_y = y;
    x += _x;
    y += _y;
}
```

the interpolation function looks like this

```
interpolate(float delta) {
     float tx, ty;
     tx = (x * delta) + (p_x * (1.0 - delta));
     ty = (y * delta) + (p_y * (1.0 - delta));
     p_x = tx;
     p_y = ty;
}
```

I've also tried doing something like this where instead of using a tx and ty variable I just update x and y.

```
interpolate(float delta) {
     x = (x * delta) + (p_x * (1.0 - delta));
     y = (y * delta) + (p_y * (1.0 - delta));
     p_x = x;
     p_y = y;
}
```

This one seems to move a lot slower but the shaking is mostly although there's still the problem of really fast movement on horizontals, for example if I update both x and y at the same time.

this seems to work okay but if I move only along the x or y axis. If I move horizontally there's a lot of jitters. The problem isn't really visible when  updating at a high delta time 60fps

at 30fps or lower horizontal movement becomes really jerky. Is my interpolation code incorrect? How can I fix it?

**edit**

adding a minimal working example.

```
static double start_time, current_time, new_time;
static double delta_time = 0.01;
static double accum = 0.0;
static double frame_time;

static int ce_run_game() {
    while (game_running > 0) {
        if (glfwWindowShouldClose(main_window)) game_running = -1;

        new_time = glfwGetTime();
        frame_time = new_time - current_time;

        if (frame_time > 0.025) {
            frame_time = 0.025;
        }

        current_time = new_time;
        accum += frame_time;

        while (accum >= delta_time) {
            ce_tick();
            accum -= delta_time;
        }

        double alpha = accum / delta_time;
        // state = current_state_x * alpha + prev_state_x * (1.0 - alpha);
        ce_interpolate(alpha);

        glfwSwapBuffers(main_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

inside of I update the variables.

```
float x, y, previous_x, previous_y;

ce_tick() {
     if(left_pressed) {
          update(-10, 0);
     }
     if(right_pressed) {
          update(10, 0);
     }
     if(up_pressed) {
          update(0, 10);
     }
     if(down_pressed) {
          update(0, -10);
     }
}
```

the update function looks like this:

```
    update(float _x, float _y) {
        previous_x = x;
        previous_y = y;
        x += _x;
        y += _y;
    }

ce_interpolate(double alpha) {
     float interpolated_x, interpolated_y;
     interpolated_x = (x * delta) + (previous_x * (1.0 - delta));
     interpolated_y = (y * delta) + (previous_y * (1.0 - delta));
     previous_x = tx;
     previous_y = ty;
}
```

the update code saves the current x and y to previous_x previous_y then adds some values to the current x and y.

Then in the interpolation call I try to do the interpolation.

Comment: `x += x; y += y;` in `update()` will do virtually nothing because these results are soon disposed.

Comment: Shaking? I don't know what `x`, `y`, `p_x` and `p_y` stand for. I suggest you should post a [Minimal, Completel, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you need some pointers? I'm kind of lost as to what your code actually does because from here every variable you've got does nothing and then gets destroyed.

Comment: You have a pair of local variables `x` and `y`, and a pair of global variables `x` and `y`. This causes a lot of confusion - to yourself, and to other people reading your code. In most cases, the compiler can tell which variable you actually want to refer to. Still, it is not a good enough excuse for using these bewildering names. And of course, as implied in the comment by @MikeCAT, the compiler "fails to understand you intentions" inside function `update`, where it refers to `x` and `y` as your local variables.

Comment: @barak i just noticed that. I updated that function.

Comment: BTW, I was referring to the `update` function at the top of your post. It seems that you have redefined this function at the bottom of your post, so I suggest that you make up your mind first, and then publish exactly what you have so far (after having tested it).

Comment: In your newly posted code, you calculated `interpolated_x` and `interpolated_y`, then threw them away.

Comment: To avoid `double` math, use `(1.0f - delta)`  (Add f)

Comment: Within `ce_interpolate(double alpha)`, see no reason to update `previous_x = tx;  previous_y = ty;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track, but you need to compile your code and fix compilation errors.

Here is corrected version of function `ce_interpolate`:

```
// Interpolation / Tweening between old (x,y) and current (x, y)
ce_interpolate(double delta) 
{
     // TODO: Check if delta is > 0 and <= 1.0

     float interpolated_x, interpolated_y;
     interpolated_x = (x * delta) + (previous_x * (1.0 - delta));
     interpolated_y = (y * delta) + (previous_y * (1.0 - delta));
     previous_x = interpolated_x; // Update global var
     previous_y = interpolated_y; // Update global var
}
```

If you are facing specific issue, please edit the question.

For more theory behind tweening, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Linear_B.C3.A9zier_curves

Comment: This really helped me a lot, things mostly work when moving horizontally or vertically but on diagonals that jerking motion is still there. It might be problems elsewhere but I will attach a video. There's also some code in the background of the video that show's how I wrote the interpolate function just like you explained. Do you see anything obviously wrong in the video? https://youtu.be/vXrQuyIfo5M

Comment: I do not have access this URL, I will try later.